# REST GET and POST on an entity having relations | Symfony 2

Tags: rest, symfony, jms, fosrestbundle

I am using Symfony 2 and the FOSRestBundle. I am trying to work on an entity which has relations with others.

I am creating a REST API, I can get all the entity properties except those which refer to other entities.

When I try to expose them, I get:

> Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!

Because those other properties which are entities are having properties referring to other entities themselves, so I guess it's something like infinite loop.

Is there any JMS Serialiser annotations that I should put on those properties or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the MaxDepth annotation, that might be of help to you.

http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/cookbook/exclusion_strategies#limiting-serialization-depth-of-some-properties